# Javascript: Put array of objects values to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I want to store properties (text length and style) of several divs into an array. Then I want to put the values of the style keys in other divs according to div text length.

```
$("#blocks .block span").each(function() {
     blockspansizes.push({length: $(this).text().length, style:$(this).attr("style")});              
});//text lengths are all different.


$(".newblocks span").each(function() {
         textlength = (this).text().length
 //if textlength matches one length value from array, get its corresponding style from the same object.
    });
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I think your question was downvoted because it is not clear what you are asking, nor what your problem is. Actually, there is literally no question in your OP...

Comment: So each `.newblocks` corresponds to each `#blocks .block span`?

Comment: I forgot a span element in the newblock selector, sorry for that. Each newblock span has text with a certain length. If the length matches one of the lengths from the array of objects, then get the corresponding style set in the array and set that style to the newblock span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the kind help, vodich. Here's how I managed to make it work:

```
    blockspansizes = new Array();
$("#blocks .block span").each(function() {
    blockspansizes.push({length: $(this).text().length, style:$(this).attr("style")});               
});

$(".newblock span").each(function() {
    textlength = $(this).text().length;
    result = $.grep(blockspansizes, function(e){ return e.length == textlength; });
    $(this).attr("style", result[0].style);
});
```

Comment: More than one way to skin a cat :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Javascript is a strange thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant push to array like that and then compare the values. You can do it with key/value pairs:

```
$("#blocks .block span").each(function() {
   blockspansizes[$(this).text().length]=$(this).attr("style");              
 });//text lengths are all different.


$(".newblocks span").each(function() {
     textlength = (this).text().length;
      //if textlength matches one length value from array, get its corresponding style from  the      same object.
     if(blockspansizes.indexOf(textlength) > -1){
        //do something with blockspansizes[textlength]
     }

});
```

Comment: This is not working. I get something like `[undefined × 1, "color: #36c;", undefinded × 1, "color:#fff;"] `

Comment: I see you have some undefined variables. Please make sure all the values that you use are there

Comment: is there a page online where I can see this and help you ?